# Function is not returning the value

Tags: php, function, model-view-controller, model, controller

I am calling a function `test()` in my controller and `test()` function checks for submit button pressed. if submit button pressed, then it will call a model function. the model function should return a value but it does not. In my controller file, it is supposed to `echo test();` but it does not.

Here is my code:

**controller file:**

```
<?php
class Controller {

    include "model.php";

    private $model;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->model = new Model();

        echo test();
    }

    public function test() {
        if($_POST['submit']) {
            $this->model->returnThisValue();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**model file:**

```
<?php
class Model {

    public function returnThisValue() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create an instance of `Model` class but you don't have a class that matches, just a function

Comment: *"test() function checks for submit button pressed. if submit button pressed"* - So, how do we know that isn't failing? and where's the rest of the code for the `Model` class?

Comment: @AndyC sorry, typo in the post. `Model` class was there

Comment: @Fred-ii- the submit button was pressed

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? You're not doing anything with the result of `$this->model->returnThisValue();`

Comment: @AndyC wow your right. so i should `echo $this->model->returnThisValue();` instead of `echo test();` because that worked. is that the right way to do it?

Comment: It depends on your use case if you want to use the result of `test()` in other places where you might not want to `echo` it

Comment: @AndyC oh i see, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to

```
public function test() {
    if($_POST['submit']) {
        return $this->model->returnThisValue();
    }
}
```

This will return the value to the calling method and allow you to do something with it, like echo it to the output.